# MPEG Audio Constant bit rate conversion

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, audio-processing, conversion

I am trying to convert few .wav files to .mp3 format

The desired .mp3 format is :

[image]

I tried with FFmpeg with this code :

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -vn -ac 2 -b:a 160k output1.mp3
```

This is the output of this command on one .wav format

[image]

I am getting the result but two things are different
Overall bit rate mode and Writing library

- Writing library: LAME3.99.5 vs LAME3.100 ( I think this shouldn't
  make any problem?)
- bit rate mode Constant Vs variable

How to change bit rate mode from variable to Constant? and do I need to convert using the same Writing library?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an FFmpeg usage question, not a signal processing question as is. (and the ffmpeg documentation will tell you how to set the bitrate mode)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I tried with ffmpeg documentation but it's not working out, that's why I posted here.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make it on-topic here :(